# What is the plural noun for a group of people who registered to a website through a referral code?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I found that "referred" is for a single person. I want to know the plural noun.

Comment: Are you sure that you mean noun not adjective or verb form? Could you give us an example sentence to work with?

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. For example, These users are Reza's _blank_ that registered through his referral code.

Comment: Oh, I see, then you're probably looking for the noun "referral" which has the plural "referrals". (From [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/referral)).

Comment: @Bitterdreggs.Referral refers to the act of referring and not to one who is referred. (There's a sentence I never thought I'd say)

Comment: @Arunkgp: *referral* can also mean one who is referred. [See Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/referral).

Comment: I see. For some reason, that meaning isn't included in the dictionary I checked. Thank you. I've edited my answer to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that indeed is the word used, then it has no separate plural form. It is a nominalized adjective.

When an adjective operates as a noun there are usually no separate singular and plural forms.

Just as is the case with words like "deceased" "Infected" etc. when used as nouns, the base form is used in both cases.

But as suggested by those in your comments, please consider using "Referral" instead.

Comment: It's not that it has no plural; the plural form is the same as the singular: you can say *the deceased are* if there are more than one of them.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. That was clarified in the second sentence. I've edited it anyway to remove confusion